# Modular forms database

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

Suppose one was given a sequence and $a_{0}, a_{1}, a_{2}, \ldots$. Is there a searchable database somewhere to see if $a_{0} + a_{1}q + a_{2}q^{2} + \cdots$ is expressible as modular form (or some product of modular forms, etc.)?

Comment: Have you looked at http://modular.math.washington.edu/Tables/ ? I'm not really familiar with this reference, but it looks relevant.

Comment: I asked this once. I don't remember exactly how I phrased it, so this answer might not be true. I was told that unless I really had infinitely many coefficients I couldn't tell. If you can pin down a weight and level (maybe only one of those is needed), this is what allows you to only have to check a finite number of coefficients.

Comment: Notice the product of two modular forms is clearly a modular form (of weight the sum of the two weights). If you only have a (small) finite number of sequence terms, you need to limit both weight and level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two databases that contain some known modular forms. One is [Stein's](http://modular.math.washington.edu/Tables/) and this is [the other](http://www.lmfdb.org/).

Comment: Fist link (Stein's) is dead.

Comment: The LMFDB is a much extended replacement for Stein which is kaput.